# The meaning of the phrase "peak by valley"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A landscape of ideas that ***peak by valley*** stretches from the
>   everyday to the wholly unfamiliar.

What does the phrase "peak by valley" mean?

Here is the link of the original context: http://goo.gl/LDivGa

Comment: Please tell us where you got this from. Otherwise, it's hard for us to even guess whether it's physical, literal, poetic, or metaphorical.

Comment: @J.R. [HERE](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dep5Eh_SUPkC&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%22peak+by+valley%22&source=bl&ots=sysfZYlxZZ&sig=6Wq3NpPgyLuyxOF68SWePu-Y6RU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3gX0UdOEAZHa8ATbooGwCw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22peak%20by%20valley%22&f=false). It's a nonce-usage, and under the old dispensation I'd have voted to close as Too Localized.

Comment: @Stoney: Sure, I could have [found it myself](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22A+landscape+of+ideas+that+peak+by+valley%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) easily enough, but I was really hoping to offer the O.P. some pointers on writing better questions.

Comment: @J.R. I added the link. Next time, I'll try to include the links in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an ordinary English idiom. In fact, Googling the phrase and eliminating accidental collocations reveals only one other instance across the entire internet, this drawn from a piece of fan-fiction romance:

> Each kiss they shared was like an emblem stamped across their bodies, every movement of their hands a cartographer mapping out a region peak by valley.

I can only suppose that this is a twist on the conventional construction "X by X", meaning "working from one X (of many) to the next", as when you examine a list "item by item" or build a house "brick by brick".

The fan-fiction author varies varies this by referring to a series of pairs: peaks and valleys = ups and downs = periods of rest and periods of excitations.

I suspect your author means something similar; but he obscures this by aligning the expression with singular **the** everyday and **the unfamiliar**. It would be clearer (but not necessarily much better) if he wrote

> ... a landscape of ideas that stretches **from valley to peak**, from the everyday to the wholly unfamiliar.

Comment: Thank you very much; that was so informative. As at the end you mentioned that you are not sure about the sentence I quoted, would you please do me a favor and take a look at the original context for the confirmation: http://goo.gl/LDivGa

Comment: @Nate I saw it in context before I wrote [and by the way, as J.R. says, you should incorporate that link in your question]. *Approximately* what the author means is clear; *exactly* what he means is not. To my mind it's just a metaphor that has not been clearly thought through, married to an idiom that is not entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is a metaphor to illustrate the second part, "everyday to wholly unfamiliar". As you travel with the author through this landscape of ideas, some of them are radical or brilliant (peaks: hard to scale/comprehend), others are more mundane (valleys: easy to understand).

Comment: @Avicenna - Good-bye! I hope you'll change you mind and drop by once in a while.